# Tracing the execution of a method using log inside a method is bad practice?

Tags: java, log4j, spring-aop

I'm currently developing a restful service using spring MVC.

I have read that logging is a cross cut concerning so I was wondering if it is bad practice to have log statements like `log.info("A variable value")` inside service facade methods.

- Should we remove those log statements and put them inside an interceptor kind of object whose single responsibility is logging?
- Is a method full of log.debug messages whose responsibility is to help tracing the method execution bad practice?  If it is, how can we move this responsibility to a interceptor if the interceptor only have access to the method parameters
- If I need a more informative tracing execution how can I achieve that?

Comment: Logging are useful in code for debugging purpose. AOP cannot fully replace logging inside a method. For entry exit log I prefer AOP. Normally I write an annotation and an Around advice which logs Classname, methodName and parameters on entry and return value (or exception stack trace) at the exit. It pretty much reduces logging boilerplate. After that one need very minimal logging.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you do not understand what a method is doing there is a major problem, you have lost control of the software.
2. There are times when it is needed but should be removed as soon as possible. Among other things log statements make understanding the code more difficult by adding non-logic "noise".
3. Methods should be small enough that they are easily completely understood with only a small effort, with only a few exceptions. See "Uncle" Bob Martin.
4. I was brought in on one project because the performance way unusable slow. I solved that problem in a day, it was the logging, I removed it and the performance increased by a factor of > 25x.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily bad practice, but you should try and avoid the mistake twitter made where it's logging messages had user passwords in plain text before encryption

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: it is an answer though?